# SSIS: how to use single variable in two tasks

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package with a `Data Flow Task` and an `FTP Task`. I have to use two `expression variables` like this:
[image: screenshot1]

(These create dynamic file names using date parts)

Otherwise if I have just one variable, one task steps on the variable while the other task is trying to use it and gives me the '*cannot lock variable for readonly*' error.

Is it possible to have one variable work in two places? Would seem intuitive... This is sloppy. Should someone change one variable without the other to match it would bomb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an Expression Task before the Data Flow... bingo

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require those two tasks to run in parallel, then force one task to complete before the other begins (precedence constraints etc.) - that should prevent race conditions on the single variable.